# Folder ACL Export / Import issue - inheritance

Tags: powershell, permissions, acl, ntfs, rights

I am having issues getting the Folder inheritance state to export/import properly via get-acl, set-acl modules in PowerShell.  I am exporting to a csv and it looks like everything is correct in the csv file but when I reimport I get error and the inheritance does not get set on the folders.

NON_WORKING EXPORT CODE:

```
    Get-ChildItem "k:\IT" -Recurse | ?{ $_.PsIsContainer } | %{
$Path = $_.FullName

(Get-Acl $Path) | Select-Object `
    @{n='Path';e={ $Path }}, 
    AccessRightType,
    AccessRuleType,
    AuditRuleType,
    AreAccessRulesProtected,
    AreAuditRulesProtected,
    AreAccessRulesCanonical,
    AreAuditRulesCanonical

} | Export-CSV "C:\acl\DirInhPermissions.csv"
```

NON_WORKING IMPORT CODE

```
    $ruleset = Import-Csv -Path "C:\acl\DirInhPermissions.csv"
foreach ( $i in $ruleset ) { 
    $path=$i.Path
    $AccessRightType= $i.AccessRightType
    $AccessRuleType=$i.AccessRuleType
    $AuditRuleType= $i.AuditRuleType
    $AreAccessRulesProtected=$i.AreAccessRulesProtected
    $AreAuditRulesProtected=$i.AreAuditRulesProtected
    $AreAccessRulesCanonical=$i.AreAccessRulesCanonical
    $AreAuditRulesCanonical=$i.AreAuditRulesCanonical
    $acl = Get-Acl $path
    $permission = $AccessRightType,$AccessRuleType,$AuditRuleType,$AreAccessRulesProtected,$AreAuditRulesProtected,$AreAccessRulesCanonical,$AreAuditRulesCanonical
    $accessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
    $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
    $acl | Set-Acl $path
}
```

ERROR RECEIVED:
[image]

CONTENTS OF CSV:

```
#TYPE Selected.System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity
"Path","AccessRightType","AccessRuleType","AuditRuleType","AreAccessRulesProtected","AreAuditRulesProtected","AreAccessRulesCanonical","AreAuditRulesCanonical"
"K:\IT\New folder","System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights","System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule","System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule","False","False","True","True"
"K:\IT\New folder\xyz","System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights","System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule","System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule","True","False","True","True"
"K:\IT\New folder\xyz\123","System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights","System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule","System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAuditRule","False","False","True","True"
```

I can not figure out why this is not working.  I use similar code to import and export individual access rights and that works but this folder inheritance portion is not.  For comparison, here is the code that works for the individual access rights:

working export

```
Get-ChildItem "k:\IT" -Recurse | ?{ $_.PsIsContainer } | %{
$Path = $_.FullName

(Get-Acl $Path).Access | Select-Object `
    @{n='Path';e={ $Path }}, 
    IdentityReference, 
    AccessControlType,
    InheritanceFlags, 
    PropagationFlags, 
    FileSystemRights

} | Export-CSV "C:\acl\ACEPermissions.csv"
```

working import

```
$acerules = Import-Csv -Path "C:\acl\ACEPermissions.csv"
foreach ( $i in $acerules ) { 
    $path= $i.Path
    $IdentityReference= $i.IdentityReference
    $AccessControlType=$i.AccessControlType
    $InheritanceFlags= $i.InheritanceFlags
    $PropagationFlags=$i.PropagationFlags
    $FileSystemRights=$i.FileSystemRights
    $acl = Get-Acl $path
    $permission = $IdentityReference, $FileSystemRights, $InheritanceFlags, $PropagationFlags, $AccessControlType
    $accessRule = new-object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule $permission
    $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
    $acl | Set-Acl $path
}
```

This is part of a larger script that I am using to modify access rights and will be using this as a rollback process.  Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!

Comment: The error says there's no filesystemaccessrule creator with 7 permissions or parameters.  `[Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule]::new`  5 max

Comment: `# identity, fileSystemRights, inheritanceFlags, propagationFlags, type`

Comment: should I not be using System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule to export/import AreAccessRulesProtected?  Is that the wrong method?

Comment: Is there another way for me to export and import the following?
    AccessRightType
    AccessRuleType
    AuditRuleType
    AreAccessRulesProtected
    AreAuditRulesProtected
    AreAccessRulesCanonical
    AreAuditRulesCanonical

Comment: I would use export-clixml and import-clixml instead.